# Am i allowed to call a view from another view?

Tags: python, django, django-views

Am I allowed to call a view from another view like this :

```
# ----- APP #1 -----
def view1(request, obj_list=MyModel.objects):
    # some stuff

    queryset = obj_list.all()

    # some stuff

    return render(request, "myTemplate", locals())

# ----- APP #2 ------ 
def view2(request):
  fav_obj = request.user.profile.favorite_objects
  return view1(request, obj_list=fav_obj)
```

It works well, but I don't know if it's a good way to use the Django views.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Hint: Add a "python" tag!

Comment: @Ulrich : Done !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!
although its better to use [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) because you may have different url in view1.

Comment: Ok, thank you. It's not a problem if there are different URLs. On the contrary it suits me.

Comment: This is normal python module and you can use functional programming but if you need to set url for view1 you can use redirect but if its not necessary you can normally use function. please press the answer link in this page.